# VideoLAN device addressing in VLC

Tags: linux, webcam, vlc-media-player, v4l2

How do I get the VideoLAN device information that corresponds with `/dev/video`, and `/dev/video1` for `vlc` targetting?

This command kind of does what I want:

```
vlc v4l2:// -vvv input_stream --sout='#duplicate{dst=display, dst="transcode{venc=x264{keyint=60,idrint=2},vcodec=h264,vb=300,acodec=mp4a,ab=32,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=1234,sdp=file:///home/ecarroll/vlc.sdp}"}
```

However I want to target my second webcam, not the first one. How do I do the `v4l2://` for my second webcam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the only way to do it but

```
`v4l2://` `+` `/dev/video1`

= `v4l2:///dev/video1`
```